# convert string date to java.sql.Date

Tags: java, sql

Is it possible to convert `string` "20110210"
to a `java.sql.Date` 2011-02-10?

I've tried `SimpleDateFormat` and I get `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "20110210"`

What am I doing wrong?

i had
 new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
instead of 
 new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd")

Comment: Show us how you used the SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Show us how her currently dining it

Comment: Check your format string. I believe you should be using yyyyMMdd.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

This works for me without throwing an exception:

```
package com.sandbox;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        Date parsed = format.parse("20110210");
        java.sql.Date sql = new java.sql.Date(parsed.getTime());
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

worked for me too:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date parsed = null;
    try {
        parsed = sdf.parse("02/01/2014");
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    java.sql.Date data = new java.sql.Date(parsed.getTime());
    contato.setDataNascimento( data);

    // Contato DataNascimento era Calendar
    //contato.setDataNascimento(Calendar.getInstance());         

    // grave nessa conexão!!! 
    ContatoDao dao = new ContatoDao("mysql");           

    // método elegante 
    dao.adiciona(contato); 
    System.out.println("Banco: ["+dao.getNome()+"] Gravado! Data: "+contato.getDataNascimento());
```