# Converting String to SQL Date

Tags: java, jsp, date

I am trying to convert the String to `java.sql.Date`.
This string I am getting from my jsp page using `request.getparameter(date);` which will return string and now I am trying to convert this String to `Java.util.Date` and then converting to `java.SQL.Date`.
For this I am using the below code

```
DateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
java.util.Date parsed = new Date(0);
try {
    System.out.println("inside try block");
    format.setLenient(false);
    parsed = format.parse(dob);

    System.out.println("parsed date inside try block"+parsed);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But the statement `parsed=format.parse(dob)` is not executing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15668329/992406

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the line parsed = format.parse(dob);

you have to add the below line to convert it to java.sql.date format.

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(parsed.getTime());
```

If the string is like "12201430" then you have to use formatter like new SimpleDateFormat("MMyyyydd"),same way for other scenarios also else you will get a ParseException.

Comment: Yah I added even that statement too

Comment: dob is a string like "20141230" ?

Comment: it is like 12/15/2014. where 12 is month and 15 is date

Comment: try new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String dateInString = "07/06/2013";

        try {

            Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
            System.out.println(date);
            System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

[Source](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-string-to-date-java/)

Answer (score 1):

You can get this done by using this sample code

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

                        nowdate="12-30-2014"
                        Date YourResult=sdf.parse(nowdate);
                        java.sql.Date todayssqldate=new java.sql.Date(YourResult.getTime());
```