# unable to get date from js to controller

Tags: javascript, java, spring

In my javascript code, i have a date of format `MM/DD/YYYY`. I need to pass this via request URL to spring controller.
I tried passing as String but because of `/` cannot do it.
What would be the best way to send the `date(MM/DD/YYYY)` to Spring controller.

js code:

```
var today = moment(); //it gives date as 05/26/2017

var requestURL = myContextPath + '/processDate/'+today+'/processDateForStack.form
```

controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{today}/processDateForStack", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public
    @ResponseBody

String getprocessStartedDate(@PathVariable("today") String today) throws Exception{

System.out.println("date : " + today); //should display 05/26/2017
//logic here

}
```

PS: Here i have used date as String type, i can use as Date type also.

I tried sending the date from js as `MM-DD-YYYY` from js code and in spring controller i have used `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM-dd-yyyy")` while declaring the arguments but was throwing exception. Any suggestions would be helpful.

--EDITED--

When i pass date value as String from javascript, value of today at spring controller is `1495823051245`.
When i pass date value as Date from javascript to spring controller, below is the exception generated.

```
Error: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.sql.Date'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException
```

When sent the date as Date from js to controller i have used `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM-dd-yyyy")` while declaring the pathvariable.

Comment: Can you include any errors that you're getting and the results of `System.out.println(...);`

Comment: @BRogers - Error: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.sql.Date'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException.This exception i got when i used @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM-dd-yyyy") in controller

Comment: Have you tried explicitly casting it to a `java.sql.Date` once you've received it?

Comment: you mean when i get 1495823051245 as string value?I have not done casting. I want to know the best possible way.Any suggestions @BRogers

Comment: This should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668329/convert-string-date-to-java-sql-date Do the conversion on the Java side before actually doing anything with the date (obviously you have to get the value first from the JS side

Comment: @BRogers - no luck , as i'm getting date value as some string 1495823051245 when i pass to controller. Exception is Unparseable date: "1495823051245". I wonder there are no complete examples i found with passing date from javascript to spring controller...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145233/discussion-between-brogers-and-user3684675).

Answer (score 0):

While using `@DateTimeFormat` make sure you are using `java.util.Date` not `java.sql.Date`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{today}/processDateForStack", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody String getprocessStartedDate(@PathVariable("today") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM-dd-yyyy") java.util.Date today) throws Exception {

}
```

You can also use "MM/dd/yyyy" pattern but in that case while requesting from js code you should use url encoding to send the request.

Comment: can u give an example for url encoding at js. thanks

Comment: see encodeURIComponent(str) and encodeURI(str) js methods

Answer (score 0):

Change separator from `/` to `-` in your date representation. Spring using slash to identify path. Also use `Date` from `java.util` package instead of `java.sql`.